# Best way to convert Unix time_t to/from abitrary timezones?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, timezone, time-t

My code receives a time_t from an external source. However, that time_t isn't acutally based on UTC Epoch time, along with it I get a timezone string (eg, EDT, PST, etc), and its based on this offset'ed epoch. I need to convert this to a true UTC Epoch based time_t.

Additionally, I need to be able to go in the opposite direction, taking a UTC Epoch based time_t and a timezone, and create the offsetted time_t, but in this situation instead of having a timezone like EDT/PST), etc, I have a Unix style timezone description like "America/New York" and need to convert to the correct timezone given daylight savings, so I'd need to get back from the algorithm, both an offsetted time_t, and the correct descriptor (EDT,EST).

I'm pretty sure I can pull this off by temporarily changing tzset() and some combination of conversions between broken-down time, time_t and timeval, but doing this always makes my brain hurt and makes me feel like I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone recommend some code or sudo-code to do this or at least a proper approach?

Comment: There nothing obvious or proper (or clear, or happy) about time manipulation in any language. tzset() and localtime()/strftime() are your best best, imo.

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is in seconds, so just offset your `time_t` values by 3600 times the number of hours the timezone is offset by. As long as you have the offset specifically identified (i.e. EST or EDT instead of US/Eastern or EST5EDT or whatnot) then this is really simple and not prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks, in one direction I do have the EDT/EST, though in the other I just have America/New York. Is there a standard function to take a timezeone (EDT,EST,etc) and return the hour offset?

Comment: No, and unfortunately the timezone names are not globally unique. If you only need to support US timezones, you can just hard-code them yourself and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

would any of [these functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) help you?  localtime(), gmtime(), etc.

Comment: These are what I usually use for tasks like this along with several other time manipulation commands. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out the correct chaining  of all the different commands and data formats and conversions  to achieve what I want, since none of them gets the actual job done.